# Swift: Alphabetize List Ignoring "The "

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I'm trying to alphabetize an array of [String: Any]. I have this so far:

```
    func filterList() {
    self.titleData.sort() {
        item1, item2 in
        let title1 = item1["title"] as! String
        let title2 = item2["title"] as! String
        return title1.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(title2) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
    }
    self.myCollectionTableView.reloadData()
}
```

and it's working fine. However, the title1 and title2 are movie titles, so I want to ignore "The " while alphabetizing, but return the full one in the TableView. Everything I've tried (like substring if the string contains "The ") just confuses me more, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Write an extension on String, something like `removingFirstThe`, then call that on both strings before comaring.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the edited, working code from @rmaddy 's answer:

```
func removeLeadingArticle(string: String) -> String {
    let article = "the "
    if string.characters.count > article.characters.count && string.lowercased().hasPrefix(article) {
        return string.substring(from: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: article.characters.count))
    } else {
        return string
    }
}

func filterList() {
    self.titleData.sort() {
        item1, item2 in
        let title1 = removeLeadingArticle(string: item1["title"] as! String)
        let title2 = removeLeadingArticle(string: item2["title"] as! String)

        return title1.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(title2) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
    }
    self.myCollectionTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Downvoting because this is just a re-post of the correct answer but with minor edits. This is also a poor way to treat the person who answered the question (correctly) in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove any leading "the" (or "a" or "an" maybe - and possibly deal with other languages too) and then compare the updated titles.

Here's enough to get you started by removing any leading "the".

```
func removeLeadingArticle(from string: String) -> String {
    // This is a simple example. Expand to support other articles and languages as needed
    let article = "the "
    if string.length > article.length && string.lowercased().hasPrefix(article) {
        return string.substring(from: string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: article.length))
    } else {
        return string
    }
}

func filterList() {
    self.titleData.sort() {
        item1, item2 in
        let title1 = removeLeadingArticle(from: item1["title"] as! String)
        let title2 = removeLeadingArticle(from: item2["title"] as! String)

        return title1.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(title2) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
    }
    self.myCollectionTableView.reloadData()
}
```

This hasn't been tested so there might be a typo hiding in there.